# How to validate real time data on website using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to validate Real time data on web page, say a [population-counter](http://www.livepopulation.com/country/india.html). I need to check if the data in DB is same as shown up on Web Page. Problem is as soon as I check the API data and then validate it with web, web data gets changed. May be, I could do it using 'wait' but I want to know the best way. I am not restricted to use Selenium.

Comment: Mock or intercept. The value in DB changes constantly, so in your test scenario you must get data exactly once, and let your page display it, and your test verify that the page is correctly built. So you need to either *mock* the DB (to make sure the same data is fetched by the page and by your test), or *intercept* it (get the data that is provided to the page, and use that in your test). What are you testing exactly? (what is the "thing under test"?).

Comment: Hi Hugues, you can check the population-counter http://www.livepopulation.com/country/india.html for reference. Mocking or wait is one solution. What are the other ways or there is not and Wait/Mock is the best?

Comment: It's a bad practice to use Selenium for case such as you have described.
You need some BI/Alerting tool.

Comment: Hi @Stas, If you can exemplify what you said, would be a great help.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question in the first place. Thought that you want to monitor the counter and wanted to use Selenium for this cause.